# How to find the item in a TSQL Select list that throws an exception?

Tags: select, error-handling, ssms, line-numbers

We have a query with hundreds of functions in the select list.

One of the functions throws an exception.

The error message does not indicate the correct line of the faulty function. It only displays the line number on which the Select statement starts.

Using SSMS v18.12.1

You can replicate this by running the following sql statement:

```
SELECT 
1,
2,
3,
1/0
```

**Output:**

Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, **Line 1** Divide by zero error encountered.

Obviously the error originates from **line 5**.

**Note:** Adding TRY and CATCH blocks do not provide more clues:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 
    1,
    2,
    3,
    1/0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT CONCAT(ERROR_MESSAGE(), ' Line: ',  ERROR_LINE())
END CATCH
```

**Output:**
Divide by zero error encountered. **Line: 2**

Comment: Comment the functions out and add-back one by one to debug

Comment: @Stu, That is what we end up doing. Just wondered if there is a better way.

Comment: I don't know if the DMV `sys.dm_exec_function_stats` could assist

Comment: I find that *if* i am using division and the divisor can be `0` that it's best to wrap it in a `NULLIF` to `NULL` the value if is it `0`.

Comment: @ThomA Yes, we employed that approach to resolve the issue, though it took some time to identify the root cause. 
I am intrigued to know if there exists a more streamlined process than debugging by selectively commenting out segments of code.

Comment: [Divide and Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) is a common and frequently used methodology, @GerhardLiebenberg .

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates Line 1 in your example because it is set-based query, i.e. one of the functions erroring causes the entire SELECT to error.

It seems that what you want to do is to go through each of the functions one-by-one to check for errors. While I'm normally loathe to recommend [cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql), it would seem that this is an option that would allow you to step through each of the functions.

Comment: @DeirdreOLeary Thank you for the suggestion to use a cursor to find the guilty party. Will try that. (Was not me that down-voted.)

Comment: No problem. Cursors are a very divisive topic & it really depends on your use case. I tend to only really consider them for admin tasks where I know the performance hit of stepping through each option isn't going to create problems. If you're performing this check regularly &/or as part of an application or process where performance is important, then a different approach would definitely be warranted.